# How to sort multiple column lists without moving adjacent columns data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have around 2000 columns with lists of numbers. The lists are specific for each column (for example Column A might have 9 rows of different numbers underneath but all numbers are specific to column A). I need a faster way to sort each individual column's numbers in ascending order. Again I do not want the numbers in column A after sorting to change how any other column is listed.

For example in column A I might have 120, 121, 110 in A1, A2, and A3 respectfully. Every column has a different amount of numbers, it ranges from 1 to 60 (in my example column A has 3 numbers). I need each column to have its respectful numbers listed in the column to be in ascending order so column A would be: A1=110, A2=120, and A3=121. I need this done for the 2000 columns.

If this is done without VBA I would prefer not to take the time to write the code, but if I must some help would be appreciated since I'm new to VBA.

I apologize if this doesn't make much sense. I've been looking for this answer and everything I see shows each column needs to reference the adjacent cells. I've been manually sorting each column at a time and it's just taking way longer than wanted and I know there must be a solution out there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Formulas will not sort data in place.  You would need another 2000 columns to store the data.  VBA is the best method for this.  Either that or you will need to manually choose each column and sort it one column at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take VBA, but it is simple vba.

Loop the column numbers and sort each column individually:

```
Sub lkjlj()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change to your sheet name
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 2000
            .Columns(i).Sort key1:=.Cells(1, i), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```